# Cannot cancel an event with .ics file on outlook and google calender

Tags: java, icalendar

I am trying to integrate our projects meeting with calendars. So far, I have managed to create an event, send it to the clients and import meeting from .ics file. However, I am struggling with canceling events. It just keeps adding meetings as new events.

.ics file to create:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//e-YKS Calendar//iCal4j 1.0//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20180606T104349Z
DTSTART:20180707T214300
SUMMARY:FURKAN-TEST
TZID:America/Mexico_City
UID:FURKAN-TEST
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

.ics file to cancel:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//e-YKS Calendar//iCal4j 1.0//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20180606T104548Z
DTSTART:20180707T214300
SUMMARY:FURKAN-TEST
TZID:America/Mexico_City
UID:FURKAN-TEST
STATUS:CANCELLED
SEQUENCE:0
METHOD:CANCEL
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

What might be the wrong with my codes?

**P.S**: it worked on calendar app on macbook.

regards.

Answer (score 0):

For consistent treatment of updates/deletes of events across all devices and calendar apps, a 'subscribe' to an ics url is better than an 'import' of event data.  Some apps treat all imports as simply that - an import of raw data.

Comment: Thank you for you advice. Do you have any further advice or suggestion about how can we do that?

Comment: Not really - if clients are on range of different platforms/apps, I think the best you can do is offer them a url that lists the meetings and send an email anyway to advise of the update else they might not see the change to a meeting.   It's up to them to subscribe and/or import/copy events to their own calendars and deal with updates if their device app doesnt.